# reverse order of python

Tags: python, string, reverse

I stuck on the following lab exercise:

> The first piece we need is a routine that, given a word, will in
>   someway jumble up the order of all but the first and the last
>   characters. Rather than just randomly moving the characters around we
>   will reverse the order of the letters. The following code achieves
>   this:
>
> ```
> def jumble(x):
>     return x[len(x)::-1]
> my_string="Alistair"
> print(" Reverse ",jumble(my_string))
> ```
>
> Copy the above code to a file and run it. Currently it reverses the
>   order of all the characters in "my_string". Modify the code so that
>   the first and last letters of the word are NOT reversed. That is,
>   instead of producing `"riatsilA"` it produces `"Aiatsilr"`.

This is my code for the above part:

```
def jumble(x):
    temp0=x[0]
    temp_last=x[-1]
    x_new=temp0 + x[-2:0:-1] + temp_last
    return x_new
my_string="Alistair"
print(" Reverse ",jumble(my_string))
```

> The above routine does not account for leading or trailing white
>   space, punctuation or other characters that might legitimately be part
>   of the character string, but that should not be jumbled up. For
>   example if the string were `" Alistair, "` the result should be 
>   `" riatsilA, ".` Modify your routine so that only the FIRST contiguous
>   series of alphabetical characters (minus the first and last
>   characters) are reversed. Ensure that the final returned string
>   includes all other leading and trailing characters.

I am  not sure how to do this, as white space and punctuations can happen anywhere, I am thinking about have two lists, one for empty space and punctuations while another one for "contigous series of alphabetical characters", using append method to append elements to each list, but not sure how to preserve index.Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The wording of your question makes it unclear which parts you did yourself and what you just copied verbatim from your assignment.

Comment: Your assignment sample code is over complicating things; `x[::-1]` is enough to reverse a string.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier hi, my question is in the last two paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
import re

def reverse(s):
    p = re.compile(r'\w+')
    for m in p.finditer(s):
        word = m.group()
        if word:
            p = s.partition(word)
            l = list(p)
            index = p.index(word)
            l[index] = l[index][::-1]
            l2 = list(l[index])
            l2[0],l2[-1]=l2[-1],l2[0]
            l[index]=''.join(l2)
            s = ''.join(l)
    return s

s="Alistair Chris,"
print reverse(s)
```

fixed it.

Comment: Not working for " Alistair, " as input. Output is "  Alistair, " instead of  " riatsilA, "

Comment: Still not working ;-) Just try with " Alistair, " and check the output.

Comment: s=" Alistair Chris, "
print "%s" % reverse(s) #output: Aiatsilr Cirhs,

Answer (score 0):

The following code snipplet might help you for the last task. 
There's no special handling for reverting of subsets, if a special char is found somewhere else than at start or end of the string.

```
# Special chars which should be ignored for reverting
SPECIALCHARS = [' ', '.', ',']

def reverse( string_ ):
    # Find occurence of 'special' chars. Stack position and char into a list.
    specchar = [( i, ltr ) for i, ltr in enumerate( string_ ) if ltr in SPECIALCHARS]
    if specchar:
        # Remove all the special characters
        newstring = ''.join( c for c in string_ if c not in SPECIALCHARS )
        # Reverse the legal characters
        newstring = newstring[::-1]
        offset = 0
        # Re-insert the removed special chars
        for pos, char in specchar:
            if pos + 1 + offset >= len( newstring ):
                # Append at the end
                newstring += char
            else:
                # Insert
                newstring = newstring[:pos + offset] + char + newstring[pos + offset:]
                offset += 1
        return newstring
    else:  # No special char at all, so just revert
        return string_[::-1]


print " '%s' =?= ' riatsilA, '" % ( reverse( " Alistair, " ) )
```

will lead to the following output: `' riatsilA, ' =?= ' riatsilA, '`

Just reverting with ignoring the first and last char is a one liner.
Using this one to invert the 'middle': t[1:-1][::-1]
Then add the first and last char to it.

```
>>> t = "Alistair"
>>> t[0]+t[1:-1][::-1]+t[-1] 
'Aiatsilr'
```

---

**Edit**

Ok, now I think I understood what you want :-)

```
newstr = ""
fullstr = ""
for char in mystr:
    if char in SPECIALCHARS:
        if len( newstr ): # Is already something to invert there?
            #Ignore 1st and last char and revert the rest
            newstr = newstr[0] + newstr[1:-1][::-1] + newstr[-1]
            fullstr += newstr + char
        else: # Special char found but nothing to revert so far
            fullstr += char
        newstr = ""
    else: # No special char so just append
        newstr += char
print "'%s'" % fullstr
```

Comment: thx for your code,but it seems not exactly what I want. I want to maintain the white space unchanged, just reverse all  non-starting and non-ending characteristics, for example, "  Alistair Chris," should be changed into "  Aiatsilr Cirhs,"

Comment: @Bob Please have a look at the last edit. If I understood you correct, this should be the one.